# What is this tree with blue and white flowers and long strap-like leaves?

Tags: identification, trees, tropical

While I was walking, I found this tree with amazing blue and white flowers and am really curious to know its name. It also has long strap-like leaves.

What is its name?

*Click on picture for full size.*

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [*Strelitzia nicolai*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strelitzia_nicolai), commonly known as the Giant Bird of Paradise. It is a tropical plant, native to Africa, but can be grown in USDA zone 13 with protection from the cold. It is a relative of the hardier and therefore more widely grown [S. reginae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strelitzia_reginae) (the Bird of Paradise flower), which has similar shaped flowers but in shades of orange blue and white.

The identifying characteristics are the flower, which has:

> a dark blue bract, white sepals and a bluish-purple "tongue".

It can grow to 30 feet tall, and has gray-green foliage similar to banana plants.